# Woocommerce: Which hook to replace deprecated "woocommerce_add_order_item_meta"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

Need to add custom meta to order items. Googled it and most articles says to use "woocommerce_add_order_item_meta" hook. This hook is deprecated in the newest version 2.3.7. Someone, please tell me which hook to use instead.

http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-woocommerce_add_order_item_meta.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you look at `wc-deprecated-functions.php` you will see

```
/**
 * @deprecated
 */
function woocommerce_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique = false ) {
    return wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique );
}
```

Basically, the *function* was renamed to `wc_add_order_item_meta()`, so if you need the function then use that. The *action hook* was not renamed and remains in `class-wc-checkout.php` as:

```
// Allow plugins to add order item meta
do_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key );
```

Comment: The hook is now deprecated, so this answer is not correct

Comment: It was the correct answer in 2015. :) But, it looks like @LoicTheAztec already has an updated and correct answer, so everyone should defer to that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49419394/383847

Answer (score 27):

**2017/2018 THE RIGHT WAY** *(Using new CRUD setters and Getters methods)*

> Related: [Replace woocommerce_add_order_item_meta hook in Woocommerce 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50579543/replace-woocommerce-add-order-item-meta-hook-in-woocommerce-3-4/50579905#50579905)

Since woocommerce 3 that has improved many things making drastic changes, the action hook `woocommerce_add_order_item_meta` still work perfectly even in woocommerce version 3.3+.

This hook is enabled by `WC_Checkout` class methods and related functions in **the checkout process** and not in `WC_Order` Class where cart data is not anymore available.

> Now as **Woocommmerce 3 has introduced new CRUD setters and getters methods**, the similar replacement hook to be used is **`woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item`** that has similar useful arguments as cart data.
>
> The **`woocommerce_new_order_item`** is really **NOT convenient** as **cart data is not accessible.**

Let see how to work with **`woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item`**. It has 4 available arguments:

- **`$item`** is an instance of `WC_Order_Item_Product` new introduced Class
- **`$cart_item_key`** is the cart item unique hash key
- **`$values`** is the cart item
- **`$order`** an instance of the WC_Order object *(This is a very useful additional argument in some specific cases)*

In this hook we will replace the old working functions wc_add_order_item_meta() by the new `WC_Data` **`update_meta_data()`** method to be used with `$item` argument.

Example:

```
## --- New way --- ##
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'custom_checkout_create_order_line_item', 20, 4 );
function custom_checkout_create_order_line_item( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    // Get a product custom field value
    $custom_field_value = get_post_meta( $item->get_product_id(), '_meta_key', true );
    // Update order item meta
    if ( ! empty( $custom_field_value ) ){
        $item->update_meta_data( 'meta_key1', $custom_field_value );
    }
    // … … Or … …

    // Get cart item custom data and update order item meta
    if( isset( $values['custom_data'] ) ) {
        $item->update_meta_data( 'meta_key2', $values['custom_data'] );
    }
}
```

Finally we can do the same with old way using `woocommerce_add_order_item_meta` hook as it has nearly the same useful arguments:

```
## --- Old way --- ##
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'custom_add_order_item_meta', 20, 3 );
function custom_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
    // Get a product custom field value
    $custom_field_value = get_post_meta( $values['data']->get_id(), '_meta_key', true );
    // Update order item meta
    if ( ! empty( $custom_field_value ) ){
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'meta_key1', $custom_field_value );
    }
    // … … Or … …

    // Get cart item custom data and update order item meta
    if( isset( $values['custom_data'] ) ) {
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'meta_key2', $values['custom_data'] );
    }
}
```

> **Conclusion:** `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item` is the right replacement hook to be used with WooCommerce 3+ and that new CRUD setters and getters methods.

Comment: It's working fine, thanks. However some parameters are not fully available. The `$order` parameter doesn't have an ID for example and apparently we can't have the `$item_id` as well

Comment: @PabloSGPacheco Sorry but all parameters are available: To get the **Order ID**, simply use `$order_id = $order->get_id();` and for the **Item ID** simply use `$item_id = $item->get_id();`…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thanks for the feedback, but I get zero in both cases. And maybe it makes some sense. When `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item` is triggered the order hasn't been created yet. Am I right?

Comment: @PabloSGPacheco The order is not saved to the database yet, as the method [`WC_Order` `save()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order.html#207-228) is used later at the end of [`WC_Checkout` `create_order()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#255-345) method.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thanks, so it means we can't have the order ID nor the item ID, correct?

Comment: @PabloSGPacheco I am not so sure, you need to try that using for example `woocommerce_checkout_create_order` hook and trying to save `$order->get_id()` value as custom meta data to see if you get an integer number different from zero...

Comment: Works in 2024 :)

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the hook is now also deprecated as of version 3.0.4.
I'm getting this notification:

```
The The "woocommerce_add_order_item_meta" hook uses out of date data structures and function is deprecated since version 3.0.4. Replace with woocommerce_new_order_item.
```

I have replaced the action name 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta' with  'woocommerce_new_order_item' in an add_action statement in an offending plugin, and the deprecation notification disappears, The problem is that some parameters now appear inside a `legacy_values` array. I use the plugin YITH WooCommerce Product Add Ons, and the product meta data that should be attached to an order is not picked up by the plugin and therefore not stored with the order. So until this is fixed in the plugin you have to live with the deprecation notification.

Comment: Sorry but `woocommerce_new_order_item` don't replace `woocommerce_add_order_item_meta` … so is this an answer? or a question?…Kindly, in both case you should update this with something right  and tested … or delete it if not. Thanks

Comment: OK, to be clear. The hook is deprecated and you get an advice in the deprecation message to use another hook. But as @LoicTheAztec  says, this hook is not a perfect replacement, because the parameters appear differently. So: don't follow the advice in the deprecation message (unless you have full control of the code). I always try to get rid of all notifications, but in this case I will have to live with it

Answer (score 4):

I know this has been answered and there is an accepted reply already. I just wanted to give another way to handle this without actually getting a deprecated message (see [reference](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/29d86dfea636c2a31bf03926d7b3a94468b111da/includes/class-wc-deprecated-action-hooks.php#L106));

```
add_action('woocommerce_new_order_item', 'saveMetaData', 10, 3); // or use just 2 instead of 3; if you don't need order id

/**
 * Add meta to order item
 *
 * @param int $itemId
 * @param WC_Order_Item_Product|WC_Order_Item_Shipping $item
 * @param int @orderId
*/
function saveMetaData($itemId, $item, $orderId)
{
    if (!isItemValid($item))
    {
        return;
    }

    wc_add_order_item_meta($itemId, 'my_custom_data', $item->legacy_values['my_custom_data']);
}

/**
 * @param WC_Order_Item_Product|WC_Order_Item_Shipping $item
 *
 * @return bool
*/
function isItemValid($item)
{
    return (
        $item instanceof WC_Order_Item_Product &&
        isset($item->legacy_values) &&
        isset($item->legacy_values['my_custom_data']) &&
        !empty($item->legacy_values['my_custom_data'])
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your specific use case isn't very clear (you didn't specify when or where you need to add this meta info), but you can use `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` during checkout.

Read more in [customizing checkout fields](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/).

Comment: Sorry about that. i have a custom post type "service" and when customer fills in the services form, i have to add a product(plan) to cart and pass service id to that product. which I have completed, now want to pass that id to order item meta. Cart will have other products too...

Answer (score 1):

No it seems like the hook is also deprecated:
PHP Error:
The "woocommerce_add_order_item_meta" hook uses out of date data structures and function is deprecated since version 3.1.2. Replace with woocommerce_new_order_item.

I also cannot find it here:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add on to Ilgıt Yıldırım's answer: in my case, my custom values did not exist in the item->legacy_values array.  To fix this, I used the woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item hook to add the custom values to the item prior to calling the woocommerce_new_order_item hook.  Here is an example of that:

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item',  'save_values_in_item', PHP_INT_MAX, 4 );

function save_values_in_item( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {

```
                $item->myCustomValues = $values;
```

}

//THEN call the new hook:
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order_item', 'add_product_input_fields_to_order_item_meta_wc3',  PHP_INT_MAX, 3 );

function add_product_input_fields_to_order_item_meta_wc3( $item_id, $item, $order_id ) {

```
            if ( isset( $item->myCustomValues ) ) 
            {
                  //iterate through array and place desired values into the meta data using the wc_add_order_item_meta function
            }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just to make things clear, this function was deprecated, but [the hook](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#242) is still ok