# Adding Custom Meta Data from Products to Orders items in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

I'm trying to get the Custom Meta data of my woocommerce products to my Order Columns in my Woocommerce Admin but this code wont work on my function.php in Wordpress Theme.

```
// Order Get Meta for PD Number
add_action('woocommerce_add_order_item_meta','adding_custom_data_in_order_items_meta', 1, 3 );
function adding_custom_data_in_order_items_meta( $post_id, $cart_item_key ) {

    // The corresponding Product Id for the item:
    $product_id = $post_id[ 'product_id' ];
    //$pd_number = $post_id['_pd_number'];
    //$pd_number = $_POST['_pd_number'];
    $pd_number = get_post_meta( $post_id[ 'product_id' ], '_pd_number', true );

    if ( !empty($pd_number) ) 
        wc_add_order_item_meta($post_id, '_pd_number', $pd_number, true);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since Woocommerce 3, a better hook is recommended *(see [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666820/woocommerce-which-hook-to-use-instead-of-deprecated-woocommerce-add-order-item/49419394#49419394) thread).*

There is some errors in your code. Try this instead:

```
// Add the the product custom field as item meta data in the order
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'pd_number_order_meta_data', 10, 3 );
function pd_number_order_meta_data( $item_id, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    // get the product custom field value
    $pd_number = get_post_meta( $cart_item[ 'product_id' ], '_pd_number', true );

    // Add the custom field value to order item meta
    if( ! empty($pd_number) )
        wc_update_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_pd_number', $pd_number );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This should works on WooCommerce versions from 2.5.x to 3+.