# Trying to save order item meta data with woocommerce_new_order_item hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

```
/*
 * Add meta to order item
 * @param int $item_id
 * @param array $values
 * @return void
 */
function cart_add_meta_data_booking( $item_id, $values ) {
    if ( ! empty( $values['adults_qty'] ) ):
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'Adults', $values['adults_qty']);
    endif;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order_item', 'cart_add_meta_data_booking', 10, 2 );
```

I have updated my code because the previous function **(`woocommerce_add_order_item_meta`)** is deprecated, but I do not know why it does not work (`wc_add_order_item_meta`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Woocommerce 3 and the new CRUD setters and getters methods, use this instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'add_booking_order_line_item', 20, 4 );
function add_booking_order_line_item( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    // Get cart item custom data and update order item meta
    if( isset( $values['adults_qty'] ) ){
        if( ! empty( $values['adults_qty'] ) )
            $item->update_meta_data( 'Adults', $values['adults_qty'] );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

See this related explanations: [Woocommerce: which hook to use instead of deprecated "woocommerce_add_order_item_meta"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666820/woocommerce-which-hook-to-use-instead-of-deprecated-woocommerce-add-order-item/49419394#49419394)

Comment: You like WC! Thank you, again! :)

Comment: Great! what if there are more than one item?  In my case it only adds new meta even if 'Adults' exists. Adds another 'Adults' and update the value BUT Ignores the rest of items.