# Replace woocommerce_add_order_item_meta hook in Woocommerce 3.4

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I have custom code use woocommerce_add_order_item_meta hook. But woocommerce 3.4.0 show error log: "woocommerce_add_order_item_meta is deprecated since version 3.0.0! Use woocommerce_new_order_item instead."
How to fix it? Thank you very much. My code:

```
    // add data design to order
function tshirt_order_meta_handler( $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( WC()->session->__isset( $cart_item_key.'_designer' ) ) {
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, "custom_designer", WC()->session->get( $cart_item_key.'_designer') );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'tshirt_order_meta_handler', 1, 3 );
```

Comment: Yes! Use `woocommerce_new_order_item` instead.

Comment: I tried use with woocommerce_new_order_item but not works. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Updated**

Since Woocommerce version 3, `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item` action hook now replace outdated `woocommerce_add_order_item_meta` hook in a much better way using [the new introduced CRUD getters and setters](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/CRUD-Objects-in-3.0) methods:

```
// Save custom data to order item meta data
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'tshirt_order_meta_handler', 20, 4 );
function tshirt_order_meta_handler( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    $custom_designer = WC()->session->get( $cart_item_key.'_designer' );
    if( ! empty($custom_designer) ) {
        $item->update_meta_data( 'custom_designer', $custom_designer );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

See this related thread: 
[Woocommerce: Which hook to replace deprecated "woocommerce_add_order_item_meta"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666820/woocommerce-which-hook-to-replace-deprecated-woocommerce-add-order-item-meta/49419394#49419394)

Comment: @NgoKien I have made a stupid mistake… Code updated. please try it again.