# Custom meta data added to Woocommerce not displayed in order item meta

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I've a single piece of custom metadata to a WooCommerce order and now I want to display this on the thank you page after checkout, however, the data isn't available. The data is saved and available in the admin, I just can't seem to access it.

```
function custom_order_item_meta( $item_id, $values ) {

    if ( ! empty( $values['custom_option'] ) ) {
        woocommerce_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'custom_option', $values['custom_option'] );           
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'custom_order_item_meta', 10, 2 );
```

But when I dump out the `wc_get_order` my meta data isn't there.

I'm using;

`woocommerce_add_order_item_meta()` 
to save the data but dumping out `var_dump(wc_get_order( $order->id ));` also doesn't show my custom meta field

is there another hook I should be using to access this data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data that you are looking for is not order meta data, but order **item** meta data and is located in `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` database table *(see below how to access this data)*.

Since woocommerce 3, [a much better hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666820/woocommerce-which-hook-to-replace-deprecated-woocommerce-add-order-item-meta/49419394#49419394) replace old `woocommerce_add_order_item_meta` hook.

> **Displayed and readable order item meta data:**
>
> To make custom order item meta data displayed everywhere, the meta key should be **a readable label name** and **without starting by an underscore**, as this data will be **displayed under each order item**.

The code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'custom_order_item_meta', 20, 4 );
function custom_order_item_meta( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if ( isset( $values['custom_option'] ) ) {
        $item->update_meta_data( __('Custom option', 'woocommerce'), $values['custom_option'] );          
    }
}
```

In "Order received" (thankyou) page, you will get something like:

[image]

This will be displayed too in backend and email notifications.

> **To access this order item data** you need to get items from the order object in a foreach loop:

> ```
> foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ){
> ```

```
    $custom_data = $item->get_meta( 'Custom option' );
}
```

> **To Get the first order item** (avoiding a foreach loop), you will use:

> ```
> $items       = $order->get_items(); // Order items
> ```

```
$item        = reset($items); // The first Order item
$custom_data = $item->get_meta( 'Custom option' ); // Your custom meta data
```

---

Related: [Replace woocommerce_add_order_item_meta hook in Woocommerce 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50579543/replace-woocommerce-add-order-item-meta-hook-in-woocommerce-3-4/50579905#50579905)

Comment: Excellent thank you - Is there a shorthand to access the first item without using a `foreach` statement. E.g. if the first items custom field will always be used regardless if several other items are purchased with the same fieldset. E.g. `$order->get_items()[1]->get_meta( 'Custom option' )`

Comment: @SamXronn Added an addition to my answer, to get the first order item.