# Difference between wp_postmeta and wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta tables

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type

Seems like both tables are storing metadata of orders in woocommerce. But how to know what data to store to where?

I'm currently using update_post_meta function such as,

```
update_post_meta( $order_id, 'newcheckboxfield', esc_attr($_POST['newcheckboxfield'])
```

to add a custom field (newcheckboxfield) at the checkout for each order. But I prefer if the meta data goes to wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta table as that seems to be storing relevant data for each order, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` is just for all WooCommerce **order items** meta data *(but not for order meta data)*.

The table `wp_postmeta` handle meta data for all post types like default Wordpress blog **`post`**, default Wordpress `page`, default Wordpress image `attachment` and all other custom post types.

Some WooCommerce default custom post types are `product`, `product_variation`, `shop_coupon`, `shop_order`, `shop_order_refund`…

---

To better understand WooCommerce orders:

- Mostly all checkout fields are stored as order meta data (in `wp_postmeta` table)
- Cart item data is stored as order item meta data (in `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` table)

---

**WooCommerce Order and Order Item custom fields after checkout**

1) **Order meta data**

To add a custom field tas order meta data, you will use the following hooks:

- `woocommerce_checkout_create_order` action hook with 2 arguments: `$order`, `$data` (see [this examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_checkout_create_order) on Stack OverFlow)
- `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` action hook with 2 arguments: `$order_id`, `$data` (see [this examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta) on Stack OverFlow)

2) **Order item meta data**

To add a custom field as **order item** meta data, you will use the following hook:

- `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item` action hook as explained [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666820/woocommerce-which-hook-to-replace-deprecated-woocommerce-add-order-item-meta/49419394#49419394) (see [other examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item) on Stack OverFlow)

Comment: This is just what I needed. I was looking to add order item meta data and I just found out this https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-woocommerce_add_order_item_meta.html but it has been deprecated since ver 3.0. You pointed me to the right direction. You're the man!