# Get product data on woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to create custom meta data in the wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta table.  But to create the data I want to store as meta data requires I know the product_id of the order item that is created at the Woocommerce hook woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item.

I have succeeded in creating a meta record with a value from a session variable but my code fails when I try to get the order item's product_id.  I would greatly appreciate a solution for this.

So the following code works by creating a record in wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta table with meta_key of "_raw_location_id'

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'raw_order_item_meta', 20, 2);
function raw_order_item_meta( $order ) {
    $order->update_meta_data( '_raw_location_id', $_SESSION['location_id'] );
}
```

So then I "enhanced" the code to create one more record but with the meta_key value of $product_id.  In adding the code I thought necessary the checkout does not complete so I never get to the thank you page. The checkout page is re-displayed with no changes in the database.  I did meticulous testing by adding one line of code at a time. I have number the lines of code below for easy reference.

I found that adding line "3" causes the error. So I have not been able to verify if lines 4 & 5 work or not and I took the code from another post so I can't even say I understand the syntax of line 5 I am just hoping it works as advertised.  I think my first obstacle is line 3.  Why is this not working?  I just want to know what the product_id is of the order item being processed.

1. add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'raw_order_item_meta', 20, 2);
2. function raw_order_item_meta( $order ) {
3. $items = $order->get_items();
4. foreach ( $items as $item_id => $item ) {
5. $product_id = $item->get_variation_id() ? $item->get_variation_id() : $item->get_product_id();
6. $order->update_meta_data( '_raw_location_id', $_SESSION['location_id'] );
7. $order->update_meta_data( '_raw_wc_product', $product_id );
8. }
9. }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [`woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#457) in a wrong way as the [hook arguments](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#457) are wrong in your code. The correct code is:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'add_order_item_custom_meta', 10, 4 );
function add_order_item_custom_meta( $item, $cart_item_key, $cart_item, $order ) {
    $item->update_meta_data( '_raw_location_id', $_SESSION['location_id'] );
}
```

So as you can see you don't need to loop through order items *(as `$item` s the current order item)* and your 2nd code will be:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'add_order_item_custom_meta', 10, 4 );
function add_order_item_custom_meta( $item, $cart_item_key, $cart_item, $order ) {
    $product_id = $item->get_variation_id() ? $item->get_variation_id() : $item->get_product_id();

    $item->update_meta_data( '_raw_location_id', $_SESSION['location_id'] );
    $item->update_meta_data( '_raw_product_id', $product_id );
}
```

or the same thing in an other way:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'add_order_item_custom_meta', 10, 4 );
function add_order_item_custom_meta( $item, $cart_item_key, $cart_item, $order ) {
    $product = $item->get_product(); // The WC_Product instance Object

    $item->update_meta_data( '_raw_location_id', $_SESSION['location_id'] );
    $item->update_meta_data( '_raw_product_id', $product->get_id() ); // Set the product ID 
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Related:

- [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318?r=SearchResults&s=1|88.4984#45706318)
- [Woocommerce: Which hook to replace deprecated "woocommerce_add_order_item_meta"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666820/woocommerce-which-hook-to-replace-deprecated-woocommerce-add-order-item-meta/49419394#49419394)

Comment: Loic thank you so much!  My follow-up question is how can I learn about using these hooks in general. How do I know what variables are available at any given point and what the variables are.  For instance $cart_item_key I have not seen before so how am I supposed to know this? The argument $order I see is an instance of the WC_Order object but how do I know what variables are contained in the wc_order object?  If I don't know that I can't get data out of it.  I have looked at a thousand posts and still can't find a good tutorial.  Anyway, I couldn't be more grateful for your response. Thanks!